nx monopero + react native error Metro Cannot resolve fs
I use NX monorepo with Next.js and React Ntive. And using shared-lib.
I am getting an error from metro when trying to use something from shared-lib im my application. For example import SVG or function from shared-lib to mobile app. But in web working well.
I really don't know why, because I kept the default Nx configuration but I have a weird metro error about fs.
It looks like if some components use something from next, react native is broken. For example in shared Providers or Hooks:
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const { locale } = useRouter();

and when exporting all in index.ts from shared-lib then in react native doesn't work and I see the error Cannot resolve fs
Here is the error I am getting :  Cannot resolve fs
BUNDLE  src/main.tsx 

error: Error: Cannot resolve fs
    at /Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/@nx/react-native/plugins/metro-resolver.js:33:15
    at Object.resolve (/Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:32:12)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:73:31)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at /Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (/Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
    at async visit (/Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)

And sometimes see this message:
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  [Error: InternalError Metro has encountered an error: Cannot resolve fs: /Users/mac/projects/nx-app/node_modules/@nx/react-native/plugins/metro-resolver.js (33:15)

  31 |             console.log(chalk.red(`[Nx] Unable to resolve with any resolver: ${realModuleName}`));
  32 |         }
> 33 |         throw new Error(`Cannot resolve ${chalk.bold(realModuleName)}`);
     |               ^
  34 |     };
  35 | }
  36 | exports.getResolveRequest = getResolveRequest;]

my metro config:
const { withNxMetro } = require('@nx/react-native');
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const path = require('path');
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://reactnative.dev/docs/metro
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const customConfig = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'cjs', 'mjs', 'svg'],
  },
  watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules')],
};

module.exports = withNxMetro(mergeConfig(defaultConfig, customConfig), {
  // Change this to true to see debugging info.
  // Useful if you have issues resolving modules
  debug: false,
  // all the file extensions used for imports other than 'ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'
  extensions: [],
  // Specify folders to watch, in addition to Nx defaults (workspace libraries and node_modules)
  watchFolders: [],
});

my webpack config:
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nx/webpack');
const { withReact } = require('@nx/react');

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(
  withNx(),
  withReact({
    // Uncomment this line if you don't want to use SVGR
    // See: https://react-svgr.com/
    // svgr: false
  }),
  (config) => {
    // Update the webpack config as needed here.
    // e.g. `config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin())`

    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...(config.resolve.alias ?? {}),
      // 'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    };
    config.resolve.extensions = [
      '.web.tsx',
      '.web.ts',
      '.web.jsx',
      '.web.js',
      ...config.resolve.extensions,
    ];
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      include: /react-native-vector-icons/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
        ],
      },
    });

    return config;
  },
);


I've tried everything. I've the same error stack down to buildSubgraph and all. I think this has to be metro config, because I've exhausted options/workarounds in webpack config for mobile.
